# Google Drive API Code Authentication returns 500 error

Tags: php, google-drive-api, google-oauth

Currently, I am working on We application in PHP, which will get Google Drive files and perform some operation on it. 
I have created Google Project with name My Project, with credentials which allow me to download the credential json file. I have Used following two files as mentioned in the google documentation 
https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/auth/web-app

`index.php`

```
<?php

 require 'vendor/autoload.php';
 session_start();
 $client = new Google_Client();
 $client->setAuthConfig('client_secret_new.json');
 //$client->setAccessType("online");        // offline access
 //$client->setIncludeGrantedScopes(true);   // incremental auth
 $client->addScope(Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE);
 $client->setRedirectUri('http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/google-
 drive/oauth2callback.php');

if (isset($_SESSION['access_token']) && $_SESSION['access_token']) {
$client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['access_token']);
$drive = new Google_Service_Drive($client);
$optParams = array(
    'fields' => 'nextPageToken, files(id, name)'
);
$files = $drive->files->listFiles($optParams);
if (count($files->getFiles()) == 0) {
    print "No files found.\n";
} else {
    print "Files:\n";
    foreach ($files->getFiles() as $file) {
        echo $file->getName()." ".$file->getId()."<br/>";
    }
    }
    } else {
   $redirect_uri = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/google-
    drive/oauth2callback.php';
    header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect_uri, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
  }

 ?>
```

`oauth2callback.php`

```
  <?php
    require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
    session_start();

     $client = new Google_Client();
     $client->setAuthConfigFile('client_secret_new.json');
     $client->setRedirectUri('http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/google-
     drive/oauth2callback.php');
     $client->addScope(Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE);

     if (!isset($_GET['code'])) {
     $auth_url = $client->createAuthUrl();
     header('Location: ' . filter_var($auth_url, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
     } else {
     $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
     $_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
      $redirect_uri = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/google-drive/';
      header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect_uri, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
     }

    ?>
```

Once I run `index.php` file, it as me to login to google account and ask for required permission, once i access the permission it moves to redirect url which is `oauth2callback.php` file with code in url, but `oauth2callback.php` once it authenticate code it gives `500 error` in line `$client->authenticate($_GET['code']);`

please give me solution for the same.

Comment: Have you tried the [PHP Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/php)? It includes the oAuth2.0 implementation.

Comment: have you solved this? can you show the error ?